# the code and the actual output didn't match

Tags: pwm, adc

i want to make the stuff, which the output is written from the analogread, but when the A3 == HIGH, the output pin 9 is used, but when the A3 == LOW, the output pin 10 is used, and when i simulate it on proteus, it seems not the same as i mean, what's wrong with the code, please need your help.

```
  int hasil
  int reado;
  int z;
  int baca;
  bool en = false;
  void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  TCCR1A = 0b00100010;
  TCCR1B = 0b00011001;
  TCCR0A = 0; TCCR0B = 0;
  ICR1 = 100000;//disable millis, delay and mciroseconds function 
  //disable millis, delay and mciroseconds function 

   // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT); pinMode(A3, INPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT); pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  }

  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 hasil = analogRead(A2);
 baca = digitalRead(A3);
 for (z=0; z<=hasil; z++)
 reado = map (hasil, 0, 255, 0, ICR1);
 if (hasil > 30 && baca == HIGH)
 {analogWrite(9,hasil); analogWrite(10,0);}
 else if (hasil >30 && baca == LOW)
 {analogWrite(9,0); analogWrite(10,hasil);}
 else if (hasil<30)
 {analogWrite(9, 0);
 analogWrite(10, 0);}}
```

[image]

Comment: analogWrite starts the PWM signal. you don't let it run and start it again and again. so instead of `|_|_|_` you get `||||||`

Comment: so how to do pwm properly sir @Juraj

Comment: analogWrite will start PWM signal. and then call analogWrite again only if you want to change it or stop it

Comment: Re “`bool en = false;`”: Yes, we did figure out that your variable names are not in English, no need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> when i simulate it on proteus, it seems not the same as i mean

The attached picture is not very clear, but it seems to me that it's
doing exactly what you asked for: a PWM output that switches between two
different output pins. The program should work as expected, with only a
few caveats. Let me comment it in some detail:

```c++
ICR1 = 100000;
```

Here you are setting `ICR1` to 34464 (i.e. 100000 modulo
2<sup>16</sup>). This is likely not what you mean...

```c++
Serial.begin(115200);
```

There is no point in initializing the serial interface if you are not
going to use it.

```c++
for (z = 0; z <= hasil; z++)
    reado = map(hasil, 0, 255, 0, ICR1);
```

There is no point in calculating many times the exact same value.
Actually, there is no point in calculating it even a single time, since
you are not using the result anywhere in your program.

```c++
analogWrite(9, hasil);
```

Here you are setting the duty cycle to some number between 31 and 1023.
Given that the top value of the timer is 34464, the actual duty cycle
will always be less than 3%. This is the reason why it looks like a
series of narrow spikes on the virtual scope.

But maybe what you really meant is

```c++
reado = map(hasil, 0, 1023, 0, ICR1); // note: 1023, not 255
analogWrite(9, reado);
```

I would not recommend using `analogWrite()` with a non-standard top
counter value. There is a special case handled in `analogWrite()` where,
if the argument happens to be 255, you get instead a
`digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)`. This is most likely *not* what you want. Now
that you started controlling the timer with raw IO access, you should
continue this way.

```c++
else if (hasil < 30)
```

Did you consider what the program should do if `hasil` happens to be
exactly 30? None of the if/else cases would then match. You probably
meant

```c++
else if (hasil <= 30)
```

but, as suggested by user11249082's answer, a plain `else` is the best
way to ensure you did cover all possible cases.

Comment: very brief explanation sir, but still don't know how to make the output the same as analog input, would you like to teach me how to do it?

Comment: @johncaren: Fix the issues I showed you, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as i can see exist in the if else statements . You use multiple else if statements but in the end you must end it with else statement . 
Use the “if/else if” if you need to choose either one or none of a series of options. You could write the above program using separate if statements such as show below but the if/else if approach is cleaner and better indicates that the program should choose either one or none of the options
Here how you do it
If (){}....
Else if (){}.....
Else if(){} ......
Else{}
here this can help you [enter link description here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~rookert/cs162/ecampus-video/CS161/template/chapter_4/ifelse.html)

Comment: thnaks sir, i'll try it